# How to resolve TypeError: element_to_be_clickable() takes 1 positional argument?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, element

I'm getting the  error `TypeError: element_to_be_clickable() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` when I run the following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://www.expedia.co.uk/'

s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options)

driver.get(url)
elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#add-flight-switch"))
elem.click()
elem1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "button[aria-label='Leaving from']").text
driver.quit()
```

I can see that there are indeed two arguments within the `elements_to_be_clickable()` function, but is the `By.CSS_SELECTOR` part not necessary to find by a specific selector type (in this case CSS) ??

I'm using selector hub to grab the CSS_SELECTOR info.

Any support on how to resolve will be very much appreciated.

Comment: elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#add-flight-switch")))    The single argument is a tuple

Comment: @BrutusForcus thank you very much for the speedy response! I was indeed missing the additional parenthesis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do need both `By` and the value, but the function expects both values to be packed to one, in a `tuple`

```
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#add-flight-switch"))
```

If you drill down the source code you will see `element_to_be_clickable` uses `_find_element` internally, this function unpack the `tuple` to be used in `driver.find_element()`

```
class element_to_be_clickable(object):
    def __init__(self, locator):
        self.locator = locator

    def __call__(self, driver):
        element = visibility_of_element_located(self.locator)(driver)
    ...

class visibility_of_element_located(object):
    def __init__(self, locator):
        self.locator = locator

    def __call__(self, driver):
        return _element_if_visible(_find_element(driver, self.locator))
    ...

def _find_element(driver, by):
    ...
    return driver.find_element(*by)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer is great and I want to contribute that you simply need to add some brackets as function expects. It worked for me.

```
elem = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until((EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#add-flight-switch")))
```